# Consolidating common data sources in tableau that have different names

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau worksheet where the same data source is referenced via 3 different names. This is due to these being merged from previous workbooks.

I want to consolidate these but can not see an option to do so. I don't want to remove and have to re-do all the worksheets.

For example I have a data set "Data_Table" which then might be referenced as:

- `Data_Table`
- `data_table`
- `DataTable`

they are all pointing at the same data set.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you open a worksheet, you can right click on the data source you can choose "Replace Data Source...".
It does what it says and you can choose which source you want to replace with which other one. Do that on every worksheet until all of them use the same source, then close the 2 redundant ones.

However you might have problems or lose things in case you renamed columns or created calculated fields in one source but not in the other etc. So make sure to have a backup somewhere.

After you replace a data source, be sure to 'close' the old one.

You'll also see red error markers on fields if things differed between the sources. As you are resolving those errors, there is another feature that is often useful -- select a field in the data pane and select "Replace References".